# std::vector out of boundary

Tags: c++, vector, std

In the code below, assert statement is working (becomes false). However there isn't any parallel threads accesing arrays. Actually there isn't any parallel code at all. When I carry the line (in visual studio) at the beggining of the function it works correctly. What may cause the problem ? I can't see any reason.

```
  void CheckProjectileMeteorCollision()
  {
    int i = ((int)m_meteorManager.m_meteors.size() - 1);
    for (i; i > -1; i--)
    {
      int j = ((int)m_projectileManager.m_projectiles.size() - 1);
      for (j; j > -1; j--)
      {
         assert(i != m_meteorManager.m_meteors.size());

        if (SpherePointIntersection(
          m_meteorManager.m_meteors[i]->m_node->m_translation,
          m_meteorManager.m_meteors[i]->m_collisionRadius, 
          m_projectileManager.m_projectiles[j]->m_node->m_translation))
        {
          SafeDel(m_projectileManager.m_projectiles[j]);
          m_projectileManager.m_projectiles.erase(m_projectileManager.m_projectiles.begin() + j);

          SafeDel(m_meteorManager.m_meteors[i]);
          m_meteorManager.m_meteors.erase(m_meteorManager.m_meteors.begin() + i);
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Did you try to write a minimal complete example? Something that somebody else could compile and run?

Comment: `SafeDel` is probably not so safe here.

Comment: unfortunately, I delete "SafeDel" lines. Still problem occures. If this code doesn't contain any logic problems thats ok for me. Than problem is in some where else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is the following Problem: the inner Loop (for J) may delete more than only one element of m_meteor. If so, the inner Loop will erase the elements of the outer Loop (for I) even faster, than the outer Loop is traversed.

Comment: very clever answer, this was what I missed. Thank you !